# Discontinuous function with bounded variation

Tags: complex-analysis, bounded-variation, continuity

Can $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be discontinuous and have bounded variation ?

The discontinuation is making it difficult for me to calculate the variation of any function I can think of.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, in fact they are useful in Riemann Stieltjes integration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take for example $\gamma(t) = 0$ if $t \neq 0$, $\gamma(0) = 1$, which is discontinuous but $V_0^1(\gamma) \leq 1$.

Comment: how are you calculating the total variation of $\gamma$?

Comment: Take any partition $P = \{t_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ of $[0,1]$. If $P$ does not contain zero, then the variation with respect to this partition is zero, since each $\gamma(t_i)$ will be zero. If $P$ contains zero, then the first term of the sum will be one, and the rest zero. In any case we have the former bound.

Comment: Yup, very clear and very elegant. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let  $f,g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ monotonic functions,which are not continuous, then $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation. Hence $ \gamma:=f+ig$ is of bounded variation and discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $ c :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a curve s.t. $|c'(t)|=1$,
then define $ \gamma (t)=c(f(t)) $ where $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$
is a strictly increasing function. Then $\gamma$ has a bounded
variation.